# rsync backs up everything

Tags: backup, rsync

I am trying to backup some of the essential folders in the `/` in my ubuntu system. I am using

```
sudo rsync -aAXv --delete --include="/etc" --include="/home" --include="/usr/local" // /home/$USER/Desktop/bkup/
```

This command should only copy `/etc`, `/home`, `/usr/local` dirs and leave the rest of the files. But, when I run this command this copies every dir and every file in the `/` dir.
  I am not sure what wrong I am doing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Includes without any excludes are meaningless.

- `--exclude='*'` would exclude everything not explicitly included, from every subfolder, even the included ones.
- `--exclude='*/'` would exclude every directory not explicitly included, but allow copying files within included directories (and the root).
- `--exclude='/*'` would exclude all *root* directories and files not explicitly included, but allow all directories and files within included directories. **You probably want this one.**

You should add your exclude rule *after* your include rules. The rule is that, for each directory and file, it's the *first* matching include/exclude rule that matters, and the default (when no rule matches) is to include.

By "root" I mean the root of the copied directory, *not* the root of the whole file system.

P.S. Your command also has the destination directory inside the source directory; you probably want an exclude rule for that!

Comment: Getting no answer to the question I shifted to using `rclone` which seemed easier to me, but I'll definitely try this and get back to you @ams